# Convert a char array to char pointer in C

Tags: c

So I have a char array, c, which has characters like this: "HELLO MY NAME"

I want to make a char pointer array, *pCar, so that pCar[0] will have HELLO and pCar[1] will have MY and pCar[2] will have NAME.

I have something like this but it doesn't work.

```
for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    pCar[i] = &c[i];
}


for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    printf("Value of pCar[%d] = %s\n", i, pCar[i]);   
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @JoeFarrell, you can do it using [`strtok()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/):

```
char c[] = "HELLO MY NAME";

char *pCar[30]; // this is an array of char pointers
int n = 0; // this will count number of elements in pCar
char *tok = strtok(c, " "); // this will return first token with delimiter " "
while (tok != NULL && n < 30)
{
  pCar[n++] = tok;
  tok = strtok(NULL, " "); // this will return next token with delimiter " "
}

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
  printf("Value of pCar[%d] = %s\n", i, pCar[i]);   
}
```

http://ideone.com/HxfXpW

What `strtok()` does is it replaces de delimiters in your original string with a null-character (`'\0'`), that marks the end of a string. So, at the end you get:

```
c ─── ▶ "HELLO\0MY\0NAME";
         ▲      ▲   ▲
         │      │   │
pCar[0] ─┘      │   │
pCar[1] ────────┘   │
pCar[2] ────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks! Helped a lot. 
Now if were to do the opposite and take that pCar stuff and put it back into the c array in the same way it was set up initially. How would I do that?

Comment: @Ashleyy, hint: you can use [`strcat()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/)